# How do I insert a comment into my vimrc fie?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

What is the syntax for inserting a comment or comments into the vimrc file?

Having trouble finding this on [vim documentation online](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2032751/1924583

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's in a different help file ([cmdline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:comment), [help :comment](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:comment)):

```
                            *:quote* *:comment*
'"' at the start of a line causes the whole line to be ignored.  '"'
after a command causes the rest of the line to be ignored.  This can be used
to add comments.  Example:
    :set ai     "set 'autoindent' option
It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command ":!cmd" or to the
":map" command and a few others, because they see the '"' as part of their
argument.  This is mentioned where the command is explained.
```

The reason it's there is because `vimrc` is nothing but a sequence of command-line commands. Pretty much everything that applies to command-line mode works in `vimrc`.

Example of whole-line comment in `vimrc`:

```
" show tab line always
set showtabline=2
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `"` at the start of the line:

```
" A comment
set foo=bar
```

You can also do this after commands, to ignore the rest of the line:

```
set foo=bar  " A comment
```

However, you need to be careful when adding comments after commands. In mappings and `:!` commands it's downright impossible: `inoremap a b  " Map a to b` won't work. The "comment" is seen as part of the command. The same applies when running shell commands with `:!ls  " a comment`

In some other cases it may also cause unexpected behaviour. For example `normal! p " A comment` will have the space between the `p` and `"` inserted, and the comment part *may* also be evaluated if Vim guesses it as part of a command.

Another problem is adding comments in when running multiple commands, which is something I often do in autocommands. For example this won't work:

```
autocmd Filetype go
    \  echom "A message"  
    \  " echo a message
    \| echom "A second message"
```

As far as I know, there is no sane way to get this to work :-/

There are probably other caveats; I chose to not remember them and only use `"` at the start of a line :-)